# When Trying to Install Tiller in ibm Kubernetes cluster, I got an error as Tiller pod not ready

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-helm

[image: helm version]

I Described the pod using `kubectl describe pod tiller-deploy -n kube-system`, I Found message like:

`Failed to pull image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.16.7": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.16.7": failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.16.7": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized`

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Thanks

[image: Here is the error encountered]

When Im Trying to install helm3 I got below issue

[image]

`Commands used:`

`1) curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3`

`2) chmod 700 get_helm.sh`

`3) ./get_helm.sh`

Comment: What is the reason to install helm2 instead of using helm3. It also has security reasons not to use helm2. Tiller service account would need access to all resource types and namespaces. This is propably what you do not want.

Comment: @Manuel , As I'm Using Cloud Shell It doesn't have root access so running command "./get_helm.sh" with root privilege's not possible. So its not possible to install helm3. Is there any way to install heml3 please suggest me, thanks...

Comment: its just a binary. download the release from https://github.com/helm/helm/releases make it executable and and it to your path. you don't need more. but please: don't use helm2. it has so, so, so many flaws in comparison to helm3

Comment: helm3 is not installing anything on server side. Instead it is using the account permissions of the current user (based of what is set as the current contex in the kubeconfig).

Comment: Did previous advises help you somehow? If not, can you attach your logs? How did your configuration look like?

Comment: Hi @MikołajGłodziak , updated the question with logs please go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM Cloud Shell is a preconfigured shell environment and thus you don't have the ability to install packages/binaries of your choosing to it. You're instead restricted to what packages are already installed.

Additionally, the IBM Cloud Shell supports both helm version 2 and version 3, and both are installed.

To use helm v3, use the following command:
`helm3`

To use helm v2, you use the command you're currently using:
`helm`

If packages and binaries you need are not installed into the IBM Cloud Shell, you will instead want to configure your local terminal with IBM Cloud, and then install the packages and binaries you need.

See the below link for installing and setting up the IBM CLI locally to work with your resources on IBM Cloud.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-getting-started

Comment: yeah its preconfigured with helm3, thank you for the information @Justin kanz

Comment: How can I remove helm 2.16 version from IBM cloud Shell ,as it is not working.

Comment: @harishhari you can not remove it, it's not your machine. Use a local terminal and install the version you want instead of using the cloud shell